# Selecting value from table on max(column) in HQL

Tags: hive, hql, reserved-words

I am fairly new to HQL and still trying to figure my way through the syntax. I have a table 'scoring' with playerID and Game Winning Goals (GWG) . I want to view the playerIDs who have the max GWG. This is my query:

```
select playerid as ID from scoring where gwg = ('select max(scoring.gwg) from scoring');
```

I am not getting an output although Hive prints a name of the column. But when I hard code 'gwg = 16', I get the output that I need. Any advice? I am working on Hortonworks 2.3.2.

Comment: Your subquery should not be inside quotes. It is a statement, not a string value.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
select playerid, max(scoring.gwg) from scoring group by playerid;
```

Here is another

```
select playerid, max(scoring.gwg) as maxScore from scoring 
   group by playerid order by maxScore desc;
```

The above will give the the player ids in the descending order i.e. the one with max score will be on top.

Comment: Thank u! But now I am having issues in even loading the ambari login page so now able to try it. Once I get that sorted, will definitely give this a go!

Comment: Hi Abhijit, although the query works, it still doesn't give the max values. I've tried the query with and without using max. I still get the same number of entries. I need to select the max score for year, irrespective of repetitive players.

Comment: Sorry but i kept having a readout time error in ambari and had to fix it again. I am also trying to display the output for each year. The query you suggested works perfectly, but when I add "year" or group by year, things go haywire and I get duplicate results. this is my query now:        `select max(gwg) as gwg, playerid, year
from scoring
group by playerid, year
order by gwg desc;`

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to do this.
Get the max of counts and filter the playerid with the max gwg

```
select playerid
from scoring 
group by playerid 
having count(*) = ( select max(c) from 
                (
                   select playerid,count(*) c 
                   from scoring 
                   group by playerid
                ) a
              )
```

Or Get the counts and order it by descending order and get the top row

```
select playerid, count(*) as cnt
from scoring 
group by playerid 
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't been able to try this since my ambari login page isnt loading. I shall try this once I fix it!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is this simple query

```
select playerid,max(scoring.gwg) as max from scoring group by playerid order by max desc
```

Hive doesn't support sub-queries.